# Removing an item from a collection in a HATEOAS way

Tags: json, rest, hateoas, hal

I am working on a project whose client uses REST/HATEOAS to get and modify data.
Here is a part of the class diagram: [class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4fxp.jpg).

A hal+json HATEOAS response of the request */group/12345* would look like:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/group/12345"
    },
    "roles": {
      "href": "/group/12345/roles"
    }
  }
}
```

To remove a role from this group I could simply execute a DELETE on the specific role. (because every role has to be in exactly one group and moving a role to another group shouldn't be allowed).
So I would add a link with the rel "drop" to the role. Therefore the client knows **if** or rather **when** a DELETE request is allowed:

```
{
  "id": "67890",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/roles/67890"
    },
    "users": {
      "href": "/roles/67890/users"
    },
    "drop": {
      "href": "/roles/67890"
    }
  }
}
```

So to delete a user the client looks for the drop link. If no link is found, the delete is not allowed. Otherwise it executes a DELETE request on the found link.

**But what should I do if I want to remove a user from a role?**
I cannot simply delete the user. The role -> user relation is not an aggregation.
How can I tell the client if removing a user from a role is allowed?

To **remove** a user from role I would use *DELETE /groups/12345/roles/67890/users/ABC*. And to **delete** the user I would use *DELETE /users/ABC*.

So where should I put the "remove user from role" link?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Links](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-3) typically have three parts

- A context identifier
- a link relation type
- a target identifier

Frequently, the context identifier is implied by the... umm... *context*, rather than being made explicit.

From what I can see, [hal+json](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) doesn't have a mechanism for explicitly specifying the context identifier, which would mean that you need to rely upon the implicit approach.

That suggests that if you want to be communicating about removing a user from a role, then you need a context that implies the right identifier.

You would normally do this in one of two ways

- have a chain of links that leads to a representation of the user in that role, and include the drop role link relation in the list of *links*
- *embed* a representation of the user in some other representation, and include the drop role link within that embedded resource.

For example, you might have a representation of `/roles/67890/users` that looks something like

```
_links: {
    self: {
        href: /roles/67890/users
    }
}

_embedded: {
    users: [ {
        _links: {
            self: /users/ABC
            /role/remove :  /groups/12345/roles/67890/users/ABC
        }
   } ,
   ... ]
}
```